# carrierwave-dropbox authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created an app on dropbox and I am following the https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox steps but cannot get the access token. 
It has 400 bad request although I am providing correct key and app secret but cannot get the link to allow my app.

Here is the error and I am creating a ruby-on-rails app:

```
rake aborted!
DropboxAuthError: Error getting request token.  Is your app key and secret correctly set?  Server returned 400: Bad Request.
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dropbox-sdk-1.6.5/lib/dropbox_sdk.rb:277:in `get_token'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dropbox-sdk-1.6.5/lib/dropbox_sdk.rb:293:in `get_request_token'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dropbox-sdk-1.6.5/lib/dropbox_sdk.rb:299:in `get_authorize_url'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-dropbox-1.2.1/lib/carrierwave/dropbox/rake.rb:13:in `authorize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-dropbox-1.2.1/lib/carrierwave/dropbox/authorize.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => dropbox:authorize
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured carrierwave

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.dropbox_app_key = ENV["APP_KEY"]
  config.dropbox_app_secret = ENV["APP_SECRET"]
  config.dropbox_access_token = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
  config.dropbox_access_token_secret = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]
  config.dropbox_user_id = ENV["USER_ID"]
  config.dropbox_access_type = "dropbox"
end
```

Comment: I assume that you have created a dropbox app and put the correct app key and secret

Comment: yes i have put the correct key and app secret but it does not give me the link to allow my app

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example hope it can work:

1- create a file `config/config.yml` and provide here your keys:

```
default: &default

development:
  <<: *default
  app_key: "your_app_key"

production: &production
  <<: *default
  app_key: "your_app_key"

staging: &staging
  <<: *default
  app_key: "your_app_key"
```

2 - in `environment.rb` file

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

3 -  then you can use in in `carrierwave.rb` file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.dropbox_app_key  = APP_CONFIG['app_key']
//and your another configuration so on...
  }
end
```

if you have right api keys permission then it should work. thanks